# Nothing happens when trying to save to a file? python 2.7

Tags: python, file

Ok so I am trying to have the name of the file as a raw input in python but it doesn't save to file i put in.

I get no errors, it just doesn't save to the file I write to.

For example, I run the code, I select the file that I have created and named "cops" the code runs through and accepts the input, but nothing happens. The file is still empty.

```
lista = {"police":"911"}
functiontext = raw_input("call function 1(save) or 2(load) ")
arguments = raw_input("input file name ")

def save(lista,arguments):
    filen = arguments
    spara = lista
    fil = open(filen + ".txt","w")

    for keys, values in spara.items():

            spara_content = keys + ": " + values + "\n"

            fil.write(spara_content)
            fil.close()

def load(lista, arguments):
    ladda = open("telefonbok.txt","r")
    for namesandnumbers in ladda:
        (key, val) = namesandnumbers.split(": ")
        lista[(key)] = val
        lista = ladda
        return lista

if functiontext == 1:
    save(lista,arguments)

if functiontext == 2:
    load(lista, arguments)
```

Does anyone here have the answer to this problem?

Comment: `arguements` ≠ `arguments`

Comment: The result of `raw_input` is a string. So you have to replace `if functiontext == 1:` with `if functiontext == "1":`.

Comment: Please don't write your code partially in Swedish. Use English all the way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`raw_input` will return a string, while you are checking for an integer comparison. Your file is not being saved because `save` is never being called.

```
if functiontext == 1:
    save(lista,arguments)

if functiontext == 2:
    load(lista, arguments)
```

Should be:

```
if functiontext == '1':
    save(lista, arguments)

if functiontext == '2':
    load(lista, arguments)
```

Note that you also have a typo regarding "arguements" and "arguments"